# connecting events to actions during runtime

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

i know how to create a control during runtime, my controller class has a IBAction method inside it. How do i connect the event associated with a control to the IBAction method. Just like ctrl+drag inside Interface builder except during runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you want to "connect" a UIControl `control` to the IBAction `-touchUpInside:` of the application delegate `self`:

```
[control addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```